# How do I manipulate classes in java

Tags: java, javascript, class, dynamic

I know several programming languages. Most of them are scripting languages like lua, perl, JS, ruby, etc.

But recently, I started programming in Java, which works quietly. So I have been thinking of a certain function that exists in JS. The prototype of constructors, that is. For further understanding of what my question really is, I will make an example in JS. Let's say you want to create an application of dogs.

```
function dog (){
this.property1 = value;
this.propertr2 = value2;
this.propertyN = valueN;
//etc.
}

//now, I will create several instances of the constructor in JS

var snoopy = new dog();
var buddy = new dog();
```

and the awesome part, that I know about JS is that you can dynamically change the information of the constructor and all of the instances that is of the constructor (as it is called in JS) with the prototype keyword like this:

```
 dog.prototype.bark = function () {
 console.log("Woof!");
 };
```

and THIS, does not only change the information about the constructor so that every dog that will ever be created with the constructor will know how to bark, it also changes so that all of the instances of the constructor gets the information of the prototype insertion which in this case teaches the dogs how to bark. which we can see in the next example:

```
var someOtherDog = new dog ();
someOtherDog.bark(); //output will be: Woof!
snoopy.bark();       //output will also be: Woof!
buddy.bark();        //you guessed it! it will also be: Woof!
```

So with this prototype keyword in JS I can manipulate constructors and their instances. Now, my question is:

HOW can I manipulate the classes and their instances in java? And is that even possible?
and if so; what should I do in order to do anything like that in java?

```
class dog
{
    private String hairColor;
    public dog ()
    {
        hairColor = "Brown";
    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        dog snoopy = new dog ();
        dog buddy = new dog ();
        //now, how do I manipulate the class like I did in JS?
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a method in class dog named woof.  Also, it's bad style to have a class start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Java is not "advanced" with regards to all the other languages you have cited: just different. And statically typed, which makes a huge difference...

Comment: You need to create a "prototype" - AKA `interface` of what a `Dog` is suppose to be. This should be generic and apply to ALL dogs.  From there you would either create concreate implementations of each dog and/or a mutable dog whose properties can be changed.  This would allow to to create a instance of `Dog` that is a given type of `Dog` (yeah, sounds weird) ie `Dog snoopy = new BassetHound()`.  You might like to have a read through [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) for a better explanation...

Comment: @user1953550, you cannot do exactly what you did in JavaScript. You would need to be more specific. There is a lot of literature out there, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create anonymous classes on the fly if you want.

Say you have a class:

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    Dog(String name) { this.name = name; }
    void bark() { System.out.println(name + " says 'woof!'"); }

    public static void main(String...args) { 
        Dog snoopy = new Dog("snoopy");
        snoopy.bark();
    }

}
```

Here's the result

```
c:\files\j>javac Dog.java

c:\files\j>java Dog
snoopy says 'woof!'
```

Now buddy he doesn't say woof - he says ruff! So we create one on the fly like so

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    Dog(String name) { this.name = name; }
    void bark() { System.out.println(name + " says 'woof!'"); }

    public static void main(String...args) { 
        Dog snoopy = new Dog("snoopy");
        snoopy.bark();
        Dog buddy = new Dog("buddy") {
            @Override void bark() { System.out.println(name + " says 'ruff!'"); }
        };
        buddy.bark();
    }

}
```

Which results in

```
c:\files\j>javac Dog.java

c:\files\j>java Dog
snoopy says 'woof!'
buddy says 'ruff!'
```

If you wanted to permanently change every dog, that becomes more difficult, but can be done via the strategy pattern.

Let's say we have the following

```
abstract class BarkingStrategy {
    public abstract void doBark(Dog dog);
}

class TypicalBarkingStrategy extends BarkingStrategy {
    public void doBark(Dog dog) { System.out.println(dog.getName() + " says 'woof!'"); }
}

class AggressiveBarkingStrategy extends BarkingStrategy {
    public void doBark(Dog dog) { System.out.println(dog.getName() + " says 'Rrrruff!'"); }
}

class Dog {
    // notice this is static - that means it belongs to the class itself, not 
    // any particular instance of it - similar to prototype
    static BarkingStrategy bark = new TypicalBarkingStrategy();
    String name;
    Dog(String name) { this.name = name; }
    String getName() { return name; }
    void bark() { bark.doBark(this); }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    Dog snoopy = new Dog("snoopy");
    snoopy.bark();
    Dog.bark = new AggressiveBarkingStrategy();
    snoopy.bark();
}
```

This results in

```
c:\files\j>javac Dog.java

c:\files\j>java Dog
snoopy says 'woof!'
snoopy says 'Rrrruff!'
```

Comment: Note that all of this is still done at compile time. The anonymous classes get compiled into regular (possibly nested) classes. The strategy pattern is an method to change the behavior of a certain object by letting the class invoke methods of the strategy object instead (an example of indirection).

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Yep, I added a complete example of how to use the strategy pattern to achieve his result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpfull. Now I know that classes aren't impossible to manipulate but not really in exactly the way I thought.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that both lua and JavaScript are prototype based, Java is not. You can use reflection to accomplish something similar, but not at the level of JavaScript. [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in JavaScript is accomplished by the prototype chain. Basically, when `bark` is not found in the `snoopy` object, it is looked up in its prototype `snoopy.prototype`. If it is found there, that version is used. If not (for example when calling `bark.toString()`), the prototype chain is traversed until a prototype is found which has that member. The prototype itself is shared between all 'instances' and since it's just a normal object, you can add or remove members to it later on.

Inheritance in Java is class-based. You cannot add or remove members from a class definition at run time unless you recompile and reload the whole class. It's a different programming paradigm which means that you'll have to program (slightly) differently for it using other techniques and patterns.